# Does linkingObjects only work for list in realm?

Tags: react-native, realm

I wonder if I should use linkingObjects on `Contract.worker` field for the `to-one relationship` in the following Contract <=> Worker schema because I can't get the data from `Contract.worker`.

I've tried it on react native but the `Contract.worker` object is empty when looping the contract realm object.

```
Contract.schema = {
    name: "contract",
    properties: {
        worker: {
            type:'linkingObjects',
            objectType:'worker',
            property:"contracts"
        },
        role:'int'
    }
};

Worker.schema = {
    name: 'worker',
    primaryKey: 'id',
    properties: {
        id:'int'
        name:'string',
        contracts: {type: 'list', objectType: "contract"}
   }
}

realm.objects("contract").map(contract=>{
      console.log(contract.worker) //no worker data
})
```

But when I change the Contract.worker field to this:

```
Contract.schema = {
    name: "contract",
    properties: {
        worker:{type:'worker'},
        role:'int'
    }
};
```

I can get the worker data from the `map` function. So I'd like to ask, was I using the `linkingObjects` wrong in the first place? I thought this worker<=> contract schema is similar to the person <=> dog schema in the document except that `Contract.worker` is not a list. But the document says `linkingObjects` can point either a list or an object property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LinkingObject works for both to-many and to-one relationship, but you'll always see the linking objects (in inverse relation) as a to-many relationship (List)

Linking objects are automatically evaluated by Realm, but you need to modify the other side of the relationship yourself, in the initial example, adding an item to `contracts`would make it show up in `worker` (which should be `workers`).

Comment: EpicPandaForce, I got it. It's always a list. I should access it like this: console.log(contract.worker[0]).